# Mockito verify match Optional of array

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a method signature like

```
public void add(byte[] key, Optional<Byte[]> secondaryKey) { ... }
```

My test looks something like

```
byte[] key = "testKey".getBytes();
byte[] secondaryKey = "secondaryKey".getBytes()
//call the method that internally calls add()
Mockito.verify(mockClass).add(key, Optional.of(ArrayUtils.toObject(secondaryKey))
```

The verification always fails in this case saying wanted parameters are different from actual. I have a similar `add` method that just take `byte[] key` as input parameter. Test on that method succeeds. So I think there is something wrong with the way I am trying to match `Optional` parameter here.

Comment: `byte[]` and `Byte[]` are distinct types. Either make the parameter type `Optional<byte[]>`, or convert `secondaryKey` to `Byte[]`.

Comment: @AndyTurner the method that calls `add` actually converts `secondaryKey` to `Byte[]` before calling add, with `ArrayUtils.toObject(secondaryKey)`. Thats why I used that in my verifier

Comment: @AndyTurner Also tried changing everything to `Optional<byte[]>` that didn't help either

Comment: Hm. Could it be to do with the lack of useful equality on arrays?

Comment: You need to use an `ArgumentMatcher.eq()`

Comment: @AndyTurner thats what I am thinking,as it works fine with `Optional.empty()`  
@shinjw there isn't a `ArgumentMatcher.eq()` for `Optional`

Comment: You can unwrap that argument using `Argument.argThat()` posted an answer with more details below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Optional` does not perform a `deepEquals`, therefore the equality check will fail considering that you have passed an `Byte[]` into the `Optional`.

You can see this bug report from a user that faced a similar issue. [JDK-8075723](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075723)

You will probably want to leverage some `ArgumentMatchers` to compare the arguments passed into your mock.

Since you have an `Optional` being passed through, you can unwrap that object using `ArgumentMatchers.argThat` which requires you to implement a `ArgumentMatcher.matches` method.

```
Mockito.verify(mockClass).add(ArgumentMatchers.eq(key), ArgumentMatchers.argThat(r -> {
    return r.isPresent() && Objects.deepEquals(secondaryKey, r.get())
));
```

Edit:

You can also use `ArgumentCaptor` if you prefer to capture the state of the parameters passed into the mocks and perform assertions.

```
ArgumentCaptor<Optional> captor =ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Optional.class)
verify(pojo).add(eq(key), captor.capture());

Optional<byte[]> result = captor.getValue();
assertTrue(result.isPresent());
assertArrayEquals(secondaryKey, result.get());
```

Comment: Yep that works. Just that the first step in the lambda should be typecasting r to the required type - `Optional<byte[]> keyOpt = (Optional<byte[]>) r;` , and then use `keyOpt` for remaining assertions

Comment: You should return a value rather than throwing exceptions in the case of a mismatch. [Per the documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) (emphasis theirs): "The method should **never** assert if the argument doesn't match. It should only return false."

Comment: Good point. Ill update an answer using the ‘ArgumentCaptor’ when i get to a computer.

Comment: Updated answer to comply with Mockito’s recommended practices